# Coming up with a counter-example for Problem 2 of section 18 in Munkres' Topology. Is it making sense?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Now Problem 2 in Section 18 of Munkres' Topology asks:

Suppose $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous. If $x_0$ is a limit point of the subset $A$ of $X$, is it necessarily true that $f(x_0)$ is a limit point of $f(A)$?

I know that the answer is that its **not necessarily true** and I can use a constant function to show that. But I want to come up with another example and here is a function I am thinking of building; $f$ given by

$f:B\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_+$ given by $f(b) = 1/b$, and $B=${$ 1/n\,|\, n\in \mathbb{Z}_+ $}. Here $B$ and $\mathbb{Z}_+$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual order topology.

Is this function continuous?

Comment: What topology are you using for $B$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$? For instance, if it is the subspace topology, then any subset of $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ is open and same for $B$. Can you see why $f$ is then continuous?

Comment: The function is continuous because the domain is discrete. It's not a counterexample, though, since you have no limit points, for the same reason.

Comment: To get a silly counterexample, consider the constant function.

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not work as $B$ in the subspace topology is a discrete subspace so has no subset with a limit point that could serve as a complete counterexample ($f$, $X$, $Y$, $A$ and $x_0$).

Constant maps are indeed trivial counterexamples: $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with $f\equiv 0$, say, then $0$ is a limit point of $A=[0,1]$ bur $f(0$ is not of $f[[0,1]]= \{0\}$.

We can even find $X$ that is limit point compact and $f$ with an image that is not limit point compact: Take $X = \Bbb Z \times \{0,1\}$ where $\Bbb Z$ has the usual topology and $\{0,1\}$ the trivial (indiscrete) topology and $f(n,i)=n$ for all $(n,i)$ is the continuous projection onto the first coordinate space $Y=\Bbb Z$ which has no limit points and so is not limit point compact, while $X$ is.